# Android: when to set Toolbar title form Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager that contains some Fragments.

I need to update the title on the Activity Toolbar when the fragment changes.

In which lifecycle method of the Fragment should I call the Activity to set the new title?

It would be nice to use `setUserVisibleHint(true)`, but sometimes it gets called when the Activity is not actually ready (Toolbar is null).

And additionally I need to manage the config change and need to makes sure that the title in the Toolbar is the one of the Fragment currently displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the better option is do that in `onPageSelected()`

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: this is best option as everything is setup till now

Comment: Thanks, yes that does the trick, but still a problem when the Activity is recreated

Comment: What is the problem with recreating?